# Hibernate criteria Alias with projection minus second projection

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I need to sort my grouped objects by the max field «timeStop» minus the min field «timeStart». Something like that :

```
ProjectionList projList2 = Projections.projectionList();
projList2.add(Projections.alias(Projections.max("timeStop") - Projections.min("timeStop"), "tim"));//Compilation error

Criteria criteria = sess.createCriteria(Call.class);
criteria.addOrder(up ? Order.asc("tim") : Order.desc("tim"));
```

How can i achive this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using sqlProjection

```
Projections.projectionList()
            .add(Projections.sqlProjection("MAX(timeStop) - MIN(timeStop) AS tim",
                    new String[] { "tim" }, new Type[] {IntegerType.INSTANCE}));
```

hibernate types can be found in the package org.hibernate.type

Comment: but instead IntegerType.INSTANCE, i use DateType.INSTANCE, coz timeStop is a Date field. Is it correct?

Comment: You can use what you need, I added Integer to illustrate the example.